# How to pass vector of items to single argument in function using R?

Tags: r, function, vector

How can a vector of items be passed to single argument in function using R?

I have the below function that changes the values of variables in a data frame.

DF:

```
df <-   read.table(text="   PROD    var1    var2    
                 1  1   0   
                 2  0   0   
                 3  0   0   
                 1  1   0   
                 2  0   0   
                 3  0   0   ", header=T)
```

Function

```
Chg.var.df.t <- function(data, prod, vars, numvar, lvl){  
  if(numvar==2 & lvl==1){
    data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- 1
    data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- 0}
  if(numvar==2 & lvl == 2){
    data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- 0
    data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- 1}
  if(numvar==2 & lvl == 3){
    data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- -1
    data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- -1}
  return(data)

}

Chg.var.df.t(df, 1, c("var1", "var2"), 2, 1)
```

Result

```
  PROD var1 var2
1    1    0    0
2    2    0    0
3    3    0    0
4    1    0    0
5    2    0    0
6    3    0    0
```

So, I guess each variable is passed to each `data[data$PROD == prod, vars]`.

My desired result is

```
  PROD var1 var2
1    1    1    0
2    2    0    0
3    3    0    0
4    1    1    0
5    2    0    0
6    3    0    0
```

Instead of two `var[i]` arguments in the function, I am trying to figure out how to specify them as a vector in a single argument like `c("var1", "var2")`. What do I need to change in the function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Chg.var.df <- function(data, prod, vars){
      data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- -1
      return(data)
    }
```

and pass in a list of variables to the function.

Comment: will that still work if var1 and var2 have different values? E.g. `data[data$PROD == prod, var1] <- -1
  data[data$PROD == prod, var2] <- 0`

Comment: Yes,     you can do something like   `V = c(var1, var2) Chg.var.df(data, prod, V)`

Comment: Shouldn't this be `data[data$PROD == prod, vars] <- c(-1, 0)` or something?

Comment: I was assuming that he was changing them all to -1   based on his example.

Comment: G5W that was way easier than I expected. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my question. It was too simple an example and didn't accomplish my goal unfortunately. I want to specify multiple variable names in the vars argument but have them go to single locations in the code with out having to specify `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, etc.